# Javascript - calculating the remaining between two related fields

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, function, input

First of all, I would like to calculate the remaining QTY (quantity) between two fields in a form; in other words I have the *actual QTY* input text field as a read-only where its value is obtained from mysql table AND there is the *user QTY* input text field is taken from the user input. All I want is to decrement the *actual QTY* based on what the user input in the *user QTY*.

I have the following code as follows :

```
$query2 = "SELECT * from store_00";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);
$n = array();
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)){
echo "<td align=center>".$row2['item_no']."</td><td align=center>";
?>
<input type="text" id="fname" value="<?php echo $row2['qty'] ?>" readonly="readonly"/>
<?php
echo "</td>";

for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++){
echo "<td align=center>"; ?><input autofocus="autofocus" onchange="myFunction(this.value);" type="text" name="n[]" value=""/><?php echo "</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
}
```

And the Javascript code :

```
function myFunction(v)
{
var x=document.getElementById("fname");
x.value = x.value - v;
}
```

The above will output in the *actual QTY* correctly for the first time, but when user changes the value back to 0 , it will decrements from the new *actual QTY* value which gives a false remaining...So there must be a way to have a temporary *actual QTY* value saved somewhere.

Anyways I know the code looks awful, I'm still new to JS and not sure how to just create a simple relation and remaining calculation between two fields.

Comment: where does `$num` come from?

Comment: @Burak Don't worry about it!  Already declared before `$query2`

Comment: 1 - you have repeating ids -> `id="fname"`, since that is in the loop `while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)){}`. So the more rows you have the more `id="fname"` you will have. 2 - You can just check if value is already `0` -> `if(x.value != 0) {x.value = x.value - v;} else{ //set x.value to something else }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't use jQuery and your question is about javascript, i've changed some things to do what you want easily. Also, the id should be unique while classes don't need to be unique. As you have ids with the same values that creates a problem, also as you stated, you don't store your original value, and this is your main problem. There are many methods for this but i prefer this as it's easy to understand i guess.

```
$n = array();
echo "<table>";
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)){
    echo "<tr class='inputs'>";
    echo "<td align=center> ".$row2['item_no']." </td><td align=center>";
    echo "<input class='original' type='text' id='c".$row2['item_no']."' value='".$row2['qty']."' readonly='readonly'/>";
    echo "</td>";
    for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++){
        echo "<td align=center>";
        echo "<input class='d".$row2['item_no']."'  data-goto='c".$row2['item_no']."' data-original = '".$row2['qty']."' autofocus='autofocus' onchange='myFunction(this);' type='text' name='n[]' value='0'/>";
        echo "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

With the html5, you can define custom tags with the `data-` prefix, and you can reach them with `getAttribute` method for that object.

```
<script>  
    function myFunction(v){
        var minus = 0;
        var mutualInputs = document.getElementsByClassName(v.className);
        for (var i = 0; i < mutualInputs.length; ++i) {
            var item = mutualInputs[i];  
            minus = minus + parseInt(item.value);
        }
        var original = v.getAttribute('data-original');
        var x = document.getElementById(v.getAttribute('data-goto'));
        x.value = original - minus;
    }
</script>
```

ps: your `item_no`'s must be unique in this example.

Comment: Thanks Burak, Your code works fine but what if there are more than 1 input. How can i sum all inputs and then subtract from the actual qty..Please Help !

Comment: i've edited my answer, check it please.

i have changed this line in php part:  `echo "<input class='d".$row2['item_no']."'  data-goto='c".$row2['item_no']."' data-original = '".$row2['qty']."' autofocus='autofocus' onchange='myFunction(this);' type='text' name='n[]' value='0'/>";` added a class which will be same for the ones in the same row, in the javascript part, all the nodes with the same class names will be used in calculation, also gave initial 0 value because there can be NaN problem if there is not any.

You can see how the things work in the javascript part.